# Huge pagefile.sys (16GB) appear in C: drive after Windows crash

Tags: windows, memory, bsod, crash

I already moved the "pagefile.sys" file from drive "C:" to drive "E:" a long time ago. But today, after a Windows 10 BSOD crash, the "pagefile.sys" file re-appeared on the "C:" drive with a huge size (16GB) - **2X** the RAM.

I have tried many ways to delete it from the C: drive again or shrink its size down, but with no success.

Also, I did not find the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl\LastCrashTime` key in the registry to delete, as suggested elsewhere.

[image: paging size setting]
*(paging size setting)*

Comment: Have you set it to "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives" to try and reset it?

Comment: Try restarting in Safe Mode to delete the file.

Comment: @AndrewMorton. I have tried and deleted it but it was recreated with same size after reboot.

Comment: @John. I have tried and it was recreated with same size after reboot.

Comment: Might you have some program running at startup that would reserve a large amount of memory?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the page file settings GUI and describe exactly what you attempted so far. Manually deleting the file is pointless.

Comment: @DanielB. I have added a screenshot to question

Comment: Try setting a extremely small size for the page file on the system disk and perform a reboot then tell us what happens to the larger file.  What language is your drive volume labels in exactly, because, it doesn’t appear to be English despite the interface of Windows being In English

Comment: @Ramhound. I tried to change the pagefile size but it was not change at all. The drives's label is Vietnamese. May be an auto startup program caused this problem, I'm trying to check now.

Comment: @AndrewMorton. Thanks for your suggestion. After checking, I have found a startup program caused this problem. I have disabled it's startup entry then I can delete the pagefile.sys successful after reboot. I will send a problem report to that program's website support.

Comment: @mcuong Can you tell us which program it was?

Comment: @AndrewMorton. It's a coins mining program .

Comment: Okay, settings look correct. Please provide the output of `wmic pagefile` in Command Prompt. Please use a code block to properly format it. You may have to increase the width of the console window to properly copy it.

Comment: @DanielB OP has found the source of the problem, if you look through the comments.

Comment: Note: the question is formally solved when an answer is accepted. We do not add "solved" to the title here. Somebody ([e.g. you](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)) writes a good answer and you accept it. Then it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for programs to ask the OS for a large amount of memory. The OS will back up that request by using the page file (I assume only if it can: a request for 1 PB might be unfulfillable without your credit card details).

If some (possibly dodgy) program asks for 16 GB, the OS will have to add 16 GB to the size of the page file.

From your question, it looks like there is some program run at the startup of Windows that is requesting lots of memory, and your comment "I have found a startup program caused this problem." confirms that.

To solve the problem, do not run that program.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Morton very much for helping me edits the post, that also helps me learned more about grammar correction. Good luck.